# Variance data analysis through a for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, variance

I'm trying to analyse the variance of my temperature data through a for-loop, in order to delete some wrong snow data.
The idea is that if the temperature is under 0°C and if the variance of the next 3 values is over 0.1 (values here just for the example), it cannot be snow (but if the variance is weaker, it's OK); so I set snow depth to 0 for these data. 
I tried to write a small function to do it. No errors, but nothing happens. My way of writing inside the for-loop must be incorrect.

```
    data <- data.frame(temperature=c(1,2,0,-1,-5,-3,-4,-1,-1,-1),snow=c(3,4,5,10,
    11,12,12,15,15,16))    

    plant <- function(x,y){
    for (j in 1:length(x)) 
    { if(!is.na(x[j]) && !is.na(x[(j+3)]) && (x[j]<0) 
    && (x[(j+3)]<0) && (var(x[j:(j+3)])>0.1))                    
        {y[j:(j+3)] <- 0 }
    }
    return(y)
    }

    data[,2] <- mapply(plant,data[,1],data[,2])
```

My final data (in this example) should look like this:

```
    finaldata <- data.frame(temperature=c(1,2,0,-1,-5,-3,-4,-1,-1,-1),
    snow=c(3,4,5,0,0,0,0,15,15,16))
```

What is wrong my function? How can I do this easily?

Comment: I don't understand the description of what you the function is supposed to do exactly. How could your function produce the intended result? If it sets the first three snow values to zero you will have a huge variance for all subsequent values with your moving window. Also, why do you use `mapply` here? But most importantly, your whole approach seems very suspect to me.If you don't trust some of your snow values, why do you trust others? And why do you believe them all zero due to your variance criterion? At best you might get away with setting them to NA.

Comment: Also, if you set the snow to 0 for negative temperatures why not for positive temperatures?

Comment: Thank you for your remark @LyzandeR . I had a look on the last asked R-questions which have no answers yet, but I didn't find one that I was able to answer with my R-skills. I only use R occasionally, and I'm trying to find the answer of my question on my own as much as possible, thanks to older questions and replies. I believe and hope that answering my question could also help other persons later, when they will have the same kind of problem and will be looking for the answer like me first on google.

Comment: I think what @LyzandeR meant was that you've asked a few questions on SO, and for those questions you have not marked any of the answers as accepted.

Comment: As @jbaums mentioned I meant that you haven't accepted any answers given to your questions. You don't need to answer questions in order to get answers to your questions. Please have a look at the tour. In order to mark an answer (to your questions) as accepted you need to click on the green tick located at people's answers.

Comment: @Roland, the temperature here is the ground surface temperature (GST). Theorically, when it is under 0°C approximately, it cannot be snow, because snow should isolate the ground (and so the GST should not vary). I want to make the difference between a GST which vary during the day (this means no snow on the ground), and a GST which is nearly stable (which means snow). That's why I'm trying to use the variance and to combine it with the temperature.

Comment: @jbaums For my older questions, I wanted to mark the best answers as accepted, but if remember well, I wasn't able to do it (I think because I need 15 points or something for my reputation)

Comment: @Roland, If I'm using `mapply` here, it's because I'm trying to use again (and to adapt) another function of my algorithm (which is setting snow to 0 if the GST is over 1°C, and which is perfectly working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding columns to your data.frame using rollapply  and then use ifelse to check column values.

```
library(zoo)
#data$var3<- rollapply(data$snow, 3, var, fill=0, align="left")
data$var3 <- c(rollapply(data$snow, 3, var, align="left")[-1], rep(0,3))
data$snow3 <- ifelse(data$temp<0 & data$var3>0.1, 0, data$snow)

   temperature snow       var3 snow3
1            1    3 10.3333333     3
2            2    4 10.3333333     4
3            0    5  1.0000000     5
4           -1   10  0.3333333     0
5           -5   11  3.0000000     0
6           -3   12  3.0000000     0
7           -4   12  0.3333333     0
8           -1   15  0.0000000    15
9           -1   15  0.0000000    15
10          -1   16  0.0000000    16
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris S. for your answer! It helped me a lot! I just changed the way of the variance calculation, but I kept the rest of your suggestion for my problem. And it seems to work quite good right now. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my solution is:

```
library(zoo)

data <- data.frame(temperature=c(1,2,0,-1,-5,-3,-4,-1,-1,-1),snow=c(3,4,5,10,
11,12,12,15,15,16))

data$var3 <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
if(!is.na(data[i,1]) && (data[i,1]<0)) {
j=(i+3)
data[i,3] <- var(data[i:j,1])
}
}

data$snow3 <- ifelse(data$temperature<0 & data$var3>0.1, 0, data$snow)
```